# Use pipe with Electron ClientRequest module

Tags: node.js, electron

I would like download an file with Electron and save my file in path.

So, i've my request with `net` module, `createWriteStream` with my path :

```
const out = fs.createWriteStream(configuration.localFile);
const request = net.request(arg);

request.pipe(out); // Error:  request.pipe is not a function

request
  .on('response', ...
```

In the `ClientRequest` doc, i see `ClientRequest implements the Writable Stream interface and is therefore an EventEmitter.`

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you community !